# How to make dot chart with HighchartJS

Tags: javascript, highcharts

as of now Highchart has a lot of solutions for data visualization but i know it capable of drawing any chart to visualize the data.

I need make chart like this.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I am guessing that you could achieve a close approximation of this just by browsing the highcharts docs and cobbling together features from their examples.  What have you tried so far?  If you post a codepen or codesandbox here with your progress so far, you'll likely get a lot of good help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `scatter` chart type:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter'
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zvga4koh/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter